# How to word my if statement in Cypress correctly

Tags: cypress

***I am re-formatting this after running a few more tests and discovering more layers to this problem***

### Current Problem

So I found that I could add a `data-cy` to the underline to signify that a state is selected. Then, I added a `data-cy` to the state names.

This is so I could try to run a test like so:

```
    it('Clicks to delete selected states', () => {
        if(cy.get('[data-cy=state_underline]').should('be.selected')){
            cy.get('[data-cy=state_name]')
            .click({ multiple: true })  
        }
    });
```

### Errors

When running `.should('be.selected')` it's selecting the first few states then throwing this error:

`CypressError: Timed out retrying: coordsHistory must be at least 2 sets of coords`

When I switch `.should('be.selected')` to `.should('be.visible')` 
it throws this error:

`This element '[ <span.css-184xmt0-Underline.css-jn1u554>, 58 more... ]' is not visible because it has an effective width and height of: '0 x 2' pixels.`

---

### Original Problem

I am trying to write a test to unselect the states that are already selected. The only thing that is changing is in the `<span class=` for that state.

*In addition, there are 50 states and there can be an x amount of them selected at one time.

Unselected span:

`class="css-mdt04d-StateText css-1x6iasc3"`

Selected span:

`class="css-ddft8r-StateText css-1x6iasc3"`

### Original Desired Behavior

Im not really sure how to word my `if statement` to check if that span class has changed and if it has then to `cy.click)` on it and then locate the delete button on that page( which is the default-buttons part of the test).

### Example of `if statement`

```
    it('Clicks to selected states', () => {
            if (cy.get('<span class="css-mdt04d-StateText css-1x6iasc3">') === '<span class="css-ddft8r-StateText css-1x6iasc3">'){
                cy.click()
                cy.get('[data-cy=default-buttons]')
                    .eq(3)
                    .click();
            }
    });
```

### ** UPDATE**

So after a little bit more digging I found that there is a span with the underline under the state which signifies that it is selected. Now I'm wondering if I could just say something like `.should('be.visible')` then `cy.click()` it.

### Underline span code

`<span class="css-1dsc69g-Underline css-1x6iasc4">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you wanna receive boolean checks for element state I would suggest using jQuery, which Cypress has in-built. Or may it has attribute which allows to get element current state.
Suppose, you have spans, and in case it has child span with underline we can assume it is selected. So with jquery it will be smth like:
`if (Cypress.$('span[class*="StateText"]').has('span[class*="Underline"]') {
//your logic to handle selected element.
}`
OR
`cy.get('span[class*="StateText"]').filter(':has(span[class*="Underline"])')...// now we have all selected spans`
It is much easier to use jquery than handling cypress chainer within conditionals, as assertions are returning Cypress chainer object, but not boolean.